# is (utility function) $\min\left \{ \sqrt{x+y},z+w \right \}$ differentiable?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, partial-derivative

I have the (utility) function with $4$ variables $$\min\left \{ \sqrt{x+y},z+w \right \}$$
I am wondering if the function is differentiable? I am guessing that it is not at every point and that the partiales exist but not sure on if it is actually differentiable. If I imagine it correctly it wouldn't be possible for the minimum function as it has "edges" where the derivative is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Observe when $z+w < \sqrt{x+y}$  the utility function is  $f(x,y,z,w) := \min \{ \sqrt{x+y}, z+w \} = z+w$. Since $x+z$ is a polynomial, then is differentiable in $\{(x,y,z,w) : z+w<\sqrt{x+y} \}$.

Analogously, when $z+w > \sqrt{x+y}$ results that $f(x,y,z,w) = \sqrt{x+y}$. Consequently, $f$ is differentiable in $\{(x,y,z,w): z+w>\sqrt{x+y},~ x+y \neq 0\}$ because is the composition of well-known differentiable functions (we exclude $x+y=0$ since $f$ is not even continuous there).

Finally, we have to check the behaviour of the function in $\{(x,y,z,w): z+w = \sqrt{x+y},~ x+y \neq 0\}$.  Observe that $ \partial_w f(x,y,z,w) = \partial_w(z+w) = 1 $ when $z+w \to (x+y)^{-}$ but $\partial_wf(x,y,z,w) = \partial_w (\sqrt{x+y}) = 0$ when $(z+y)\to (x+y)^{+}$. Since, the partial derivative $\partial_w$ is not well defined there, $f$ is not differentiable in $\{(x,y,z,w): z+w = \sqrt{x+y},~ x+y \neq 0\}$.

Comment: Wouldn't the last paragraph alone be sufficient in this case then to argue $f$ is not differentaible?

Comment: It should be noted it is on $\mathbb{R}^4$ the function is defined***

Comment: @mathstudent23 It is too vague say $f$ is not differentiable. Is it non-differentiable everywhere?, is non-differentiable in a specific point or domain? For that reason I specify where is differentiable and where not.

Comment: Hmm so since the utility is only defiend in $\mathbb{R}_+^4$ then it is just not differentiable right?'

Comment: It is differentiable only in the set $\{(x,y,z,w) \in \mathbb{R}^4: z+w < \sqrt{x+y}\} \cup \{(x,y,z,w) \in \mathbb{R}^4: z+w >\sqrt{x+y},~ x+y \neq 0 \}$

Comment: You mean $z+w$ is a poly, right?

Comment: And are the $\rightarrow$ not wrong?